# How to execute an application that's injected in a process

Tags: c++, process, execute, inject

I want to execute an application (executable ending with an .exe extension ) that is injected in a process on WINDOWS. How do I do that?

Comment: Too lazy to formulate a proper question? Then I'll just answer `CreateThread`.

Comment: What is injected in another process? Is it an exe?

Comment: I think you need to read up on your terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CreateRemoteThread`. This Win32 API starts a thread in another process.